# without key store possible upload to Google Play in phoneGap

Tags: cordova

I have lost my keystore password. Is it possible to upload my app to Google Play without my keystore password?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. Post your application as the new one (with different package name).

Create new Keystore and e-mail it to yourself for safe keeping.